# Facebook dialog post with embedded swf showing only sometimes

Tags: facebook, flash

I'm trying to do a basic facebook wall post with an embedded flash object based on the following documentation:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

I'd like to do this using just a direct URL, like (note parameters get encoded):

```
https://www.facebook.com/dialog/feed?
app_id=SOME_APP_ID&
link=http://www.myregisteredfbdomain.com/someurl&
picture=http://www.myregisteredfbdomain.com/cfg/media/imagelink.png&
name=Flash%20Test&
caption=Just%20a%20test&
description=A%20Description&
redirect_uri=http://www.myregisteredfbdomain.com/someurl&
source=http://www.myregisteredfbdomain.com/facebook/aflashfile.swf
```

Although I've also tried it using javascript, with the same result:

```
<script> 
  FB.init({appId: SOME_APP_ID, status: true, cookie: true});

  function postToFeed() {
     var obj = {
       method: 'feed',
       redirect_uri: 'http://www.myregisteredfbdomain.com/someurl',
       link: 'http://www.myregisteredfbdomain.com/someurl',
       picture: 'http://www.myregisteredfbdomain.com/cfg/media/imagelink.png',
       name: 'Flash Test',
       description: 'A Description',
       source: 'http://www.myregisteredfbdomain.com/facebook/aflashfile.swf'
     };

     function callback(response) {
       document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = "Post ID: " + response['post_id'];
     }
  FB.ui(obj, callback);
  }
</script>
```

When I do the post under my development fb account, the post shows up fine, and I can click on the icon which displays the flash correctly.

However when I post under my own personal fb account, the post shows with the image only, but no flash activation when I click it - it just goes to the link/redirect link I defined.

Can anyone give me any pointers as to why this might be the case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out why - It's because I'm accessing the post to my personal account through a https connection, which doesn't show the flash - it's linked via a http connection.